# Highcharts piecharts no data display

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

I am using highcharts pie charts. I am geting the series data from a
 text file. If I have no data in text file, can I display 'no data' text display at the center  of the circle?

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare two divs, first with potentional highcharts, second (hidden, positioned) with alert. Then when you use ajax, and you have data, chart is initialized, in other way (no data) hidden alert is visible.